# Team Explorer Everywhere warning in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, team-explorer-everywhere

I am using Eclipse Juno with TEE for Android development and storing my source code in Team Foundation Service.

When doing development or running code I get the following error in Eclipse console under "Team Foundation Server Messages":
The source control folder tree could not be refreshed.  See the program log files for error details.

What should be done to resolve this error? Where are the program log files mentioned above?

Update: 
I checked the logs through Help >> Team Explorer Support.
There are two log records under "Team Explorer Logs" and even tough they are timestamped 5 minutes ago, both of them are empty.
There is another log called "Platform Log", which is not empty but contains nothing about a "Source Control Tree". And it is big. Around 500K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to view your logs is to go to Help -> Team Explorer Support.  The logs tab will show you the log files from the last several invocations of Eclipse.

They're also stored on the filesystem at:

- Windows: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\[version]\Logs`
- Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Team Foundation/[version]/Logs`
- Unix: `~/.microsoft/Team Foundation/[version]/Logs`

Where `[version]` is `3.0` for TEE 2010 and `4.0` for TEE 2012.  You're looking for the `teamexplorer-plugin` logs.

If your logs are blank, this is usually because you have Mylyn installed and it has decided to override your commons logging configuration (for all of Eclipse, and all Eclipse plugins) with one that doesn't write log files, thanks to [Eclipse bug 353168](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=353168).  You should be able to work around this by either:

1. Temporarily uninstalling Mylyn, or
2. Editing your `eclipse.ini` to pass a new system property:

   ```
   -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
   ```

Please let us know if there's any additional error messages in the logs.

Comment: @e-mre: if your log file is blank, please see my edits.  Unfortunately, Mylyn sets an Eclipse-wide logging default and does so heinously.

Comment: I edited eclipse.ini and added your line to the very end. Now log records build up. When I look at logs I see a lot of "credentials must not be null" exception. I also get this exception in the Eclipse Team Explorer at arbitrary points, even though I log in at Eclipse startup. Somehow exceptions seem to stop when I open Visual Studio, connect to TFService through VS and poke Eclipse afterwards. It might just be coincidence as well.

Comment: @e-mre: Interesting -- can you tell me what version of the Plug-in for Eclipse you're running?  If you haven't upgraded to TEE 2012 w/ Update 1 (11.0.0.1211), can you do so?  Does this change any of the behavior?

Comment: I've downloaded and installed the plug-in today. Eclipse about window shows version number 11.0.0.201211191425. I can't find docs on how to uninstall TEE. If you can tell me I can try uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: @e-mre: One final question - do you use a proxy to get to the outside world from your local network?  (Or to `tfspreview.com` in particular?)

Comment: Yes we are using a proxy here at my workplace. I've the proxy configured in Internet Explorer and I have no problem accessing visualstudio.com or the sub-domain for my projects with any browser. I also checked Eclipse settings and confirmed that the correct proxy is set under "Window >> Preferences >> General >> Network Connections" (I didn't set it, Eclipse got it auto)

Comment: I managed to uninstall and reinstall TFS plug-in. Will get back to you on the result in a few minutes.

Comment: I'll dig into this a little bit.  But could you also change your proxy settings in Eclipse to "Manual" and specify them directly?  Eclipse sometimes has issues with the "Native" mode and actually detecting the accurate proxy settings (regardless of what it shows in the UI.)  I don't know that this will have an effect, but it *may*.

Comment: Uninstalling and re-installing the plug-in seems to have done it. Everything is error-free for some time now. I'll update you if the error occurs again.

Comment: For diagnostic purposes I will explain my experience today.I first tried to install plug-in from dl.microsoft.com and Eclipse had errors downloading some of the bits and pieces so I installed through zip archive instead.The second install was flawless (apparently at least) and plug-in was working but with the occasional misbehaviors I explained above.I kept getting "Credentials must not be null" errors at arbitrary points. The working solution seems to be insisting on connecting again and again  through Eclipse or opening a Visual Studio and make it connect to TFService.

Comment: :Having the "Credentials must not be empty" error again and beginning to think this has something to do with the server.Here are my exact steps: I open Eclipse and select workspace.Eclipse window opens and gives me an error saying cannot connect to most recent TFS because "Credentials must not be null".I click OK, check Team Explorer pane and see that it is not connected.I select "Connect to TFS" and "Select Team Project" window pops.I select a TFS server to connect and get the error again.I try again and get the error again and again.I minimize Eclipse and open Visual Studio. contd...

Comment: ...VS connects to TFS and shows content in Team Explorer. I go back to already open Eclipse window and select my TFService url to connect. This time another window pops with TFService login page in it and asks me for my credentials. I enter my credentials and everything is OK... Now comes the funny part.I shut my computer down and restart it. I start Eclipse. I select "Connect to TFS" in Team Explorer window and a window with login page pops. No errors even after restart... I cannot discover the error pattern here. After all this I really think this has got something to do with TFService.

Comment: Final situation: I started having unusual errors in VS too. Searched the web a little. Saw some posts recommending to clean TE cache folder. I cleaned team explorer cache folders and everything seems to be OK for both VS and Eclipse.