# "Credentials must not be null" when connecting to TFS server from Eclipse with TEE

Tags: eclipse, tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

I'm having regular problems connecting my Eclipse workspace to my TFS server using Team Explorer Everywhere.

When I select my server in the "Add Existing Team Project" dialog, I get a dialog with the title "Connection Failed" that says "Error connecting to server: credentials must not be null"

It doesn't happen every time, but certainly more often than not. At the same time that this error occurs, I can successfully connect to the same server using Visual Studio 2010.

I have Eclipse Indigo SR2 (build 20120216-1857) with TFS plugin-in 11.0.0.201212121120 on  Windows XP Professional x64 Edition SP2.

I followed the instructions in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidmcg/archive/2007/05/25/changing-team-foundation-server-credentials.aspx to make sure I didn't have any unwanted cached credentials (although I don't HAVE any other credentials that I could ever have used).

What does this error mean? I presume that my Windows credentials will be used to connect to the TFS server, and demonstrably this works (always, using VS2010, and on occasion, using Eclipse/TEE).

Comment: Added TEE tag. Might be more suited for SuperUser instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: Called in the cavalry... https://twitter.com/jessehouwing/status/291133037654204416

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the exact same problem. The solution for me was to clear cache folder for TFS Client Client. They are located under:

C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache

Delete everything in that folder. There might be more than one version installed on your machine. Make sure you clean them all.
1.0/Cache
2.0/Cahce
etc...

A workaround that worked sometimes was to open Visual Studio before Eclipse. Somehow Eclipse gave less errors when VS was open and authenticated to TFS.

Here is a similar question I asked about it earlier. It was answered by a guy from TEE developer team. I bet it is worth looking:
[Team Explorer Everywhere warning in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766690/team-explorer-everywhere-warning-in-eclipse/13766782#comment19019820_13766782)

Comment: Clearing the cache didn't help today, but authenticating via VS and then connecting to the TFS server in Eclipse worked. It's been so unpredictable - just as you state in your linked question - that it's going to be a few days before I'm sure that's a reliable fix. Starting VS first would probably be an acceptable workaround for us, albeit a bit disappointing (we're piloting this tool combination not out of choice, but to satisfy the rest of the enterprise).